# PHP, How can i get the values from associative array by level

Tags: php, arrays

my question is how can i get all values from determined level of some array, i have this array:

```
array (size=4)
  'Azul' => 
    array (size=2)
      '128GB' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Cristal' => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
          'Plastico' => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Cristal' => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
  'Blanco' => 
    array (size=2)
      '32GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Plastico' => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Madera' => string 'Madera' (length=6)
  'Dorado' => 
    array (size=1)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Plastico' => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
  'Verde' => 
    array (size=1)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Madera' => string 'Madera' (length=6)
```

And i want get the first level with this recursive function, but i cant find more deeper than 2 levels for example i need the first level and i get:

Azul, Blanco, Dorado, Verde

But i need the second level of Azul i get:
128GB, 64GB

The questions is, if i need the 3rd level of Azul and 64GB, what can i do to get this, having the keys Azul and 64GB or level 3.

My recursive but buggy function is this:

```
function recursive($array, $level, $itemLVL)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            //If $value is an array.
            if (is_array($value)) {
                //We need to loop through it.
                if ($level == $itemLVL) {
                    //echo "<br> Key: $key - Nivel:$level $itemLVL";
                    echo "<option value='$key'>$key</option>";
                }
                
                recursive($value, $level + 1, $itemLVL);
            } elseif ($level == $itemLVL) {
                echo "<option value='$key'>$key</option>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the keys `Azul` and `64GB`?

Comment: Yes, i have a selects that have that keys, but when i need the second level i have Azul only and i would like to get 64GB and 128GB Only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the key names and order, then something like this will return what is under those keys:

```
function get_array_path($path, $array) {
    $temp =& $array;

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Pass an array of the keys in order:

```
$result = get_array_path(['Azul', '64GB'], $array);
```

If you just want the keys under the path and not everything else, then pass `false` as the third argument:

```
function get_array_path($path, $array, $values=true) {
    $temp =& $array;

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    if($values === false) {
        $temp = array_keys($temp);
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Comment: Wow that's it, but when i want only Azul, i get the sub-array, what can i do to get only 128GB and 64GB without their sub arrays?

Comment: Just  get the keys from the `Azul` like `$result = array_keys(get_array_path(['Azul'], $array));`  or when you loop the result just use the keys and not the subarrays `foreach($result as $k => $v)` and just use `$k`.